# Inserting a python list in a column in google sheet using gspread and sheet api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a python list which contains a list of software names:
list = ['CodeBlocks', 'Foxit Software', 'GSettings', 'Wintertree', 'WordWeb']

I want to insert this list in a column in google sheet
[image]

how to insert it using gspread and api in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I have a python list which contains a list of software names: list = ['CodeBlocks', 'Foxit Software', 'GSettings', 'Wintertree', 'WordWeb']`, `I want to insert this list in a column in google sheet enter image description here` and `how to insert it using gspread and api in python`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the value of `list = ['CodeBlocks', 'Foxit Software', 'GSettings', 'Wintertree', 'WordWeb']` to the column "E" of Google Spreadsheet using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
import gspread

client = gspread.oauth(###) # Please use your client.

sampleValue = ["CodeBlocks", "Foxit Software", "GSettings", "Wintertree", "WordWeb"] # This is from your question.

spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

sheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId).worksheet(sheetName)
sheet.update("E1", [[e] for e in sampleValue], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this sample, `["CodeBlocks", "Foxit Software", "GSettings", "Wintertree", "WordWeb"]` is required to convert to `[["CodeBlocks"], ["Foxit Software"], ["GSettings"], ["Wintertree"], ["WordWeb"]]` at `[[e] for e in sampleValue]`.
- When this script is run, the values of `['CodeBlocks', 'Foxit Software', 'GSettings', 'Wintertree', 'WordWeb']` is put into the column "E".
- If you want to set the row number, please modify `E1`. When `E1` is modified to `E10`, the value is put from "E10".

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to use Sheets API and your client can be used for putting values to Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this. If you want the information about Authorization, you can read it at [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/oauth2.html).

#### Reference:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

Comment: @ijahan Thank you for replying. When this answer was useful, I'm glad.